# How do I convert a list into a dictionary grouped by object name?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Say I have a list with classes:

```
[Blue((2, 1)), Blue((4, 2)), Orange((3, 2))]
```

How would I convert it into a dictionary of this format using Python, while also using no imports:

```
{'Blue': [Blue((2, 1)), Blue((4, 2))], 'Orange': [Orange((3, 2))]}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What have you already tried? Looking at this, to me it seems dead-simple, but maybe you're just starting out. Please [edit] and add your best attempt. While you're there, please add details to the title, like for example, "How do I convert a list into a dictionary **grouped by object name**?" For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: Nobody but you knows what `Blue` and `Orange` are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `Blue` and `Orange` are classes, you can find the classname of each object using `type()` and the `__name__` attribute. Then, you can collect instances of each class into lists using a `collections.defaultdict`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for item in data:
    result[type(item).__name__].append(item)

print(result)
```

---

If you can't use imports, you can use `.setdefault()` instead:

```py
result = {}
for item in data:
    result.setdefault(type(item).__name__, []).append(item)

print(result)
```

Comment: You are correct they are classes, and that makes sense but for this specific situation, I am not allowed to use imports, is there a way to do it without collections?

Comment: Thank you very much, worked a charm. Sorry for the basic and poorly worded question, just starting out.

Comment: @GubyM8 No worries. I would recommend reading [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on creating minimal reproducible examples for future questions. We're happy to help beginners, but we need enough information from you about the problem in order to help. If you have any other questions, let me know; otherwise, remember to accept the answer you found most helpful.